# How to Calculate Hours Worked per Hour

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create visualizations on our production line. We have two lines with several hundred folks, each with different crew shift strategies. I've been able to produce the results I want in Access by looping through the records. **I'd like to upscale it to SQL Server and improve the speed.**

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

[image]

---

Here is the VBA code that works in Access.

```
Public Function MakeLaborData()

Dim db As dao.Database
Dim rs As dao.Recordset
Dim hr As Date
Dim LaborOn As Date
Dim LaborOff As Date
Dim Hours As Double

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("t_Labor") 'myTable is a MS-Access table created previously
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("t_Labor_by_Hour")

Do While Not rs1.EOF
    LaborOn = rs1.Fields("LABOR_ON").Value
    If IsNull(rs1.Fields("LABOR_OFF").Value) Then
      LaborOff = Now()
    Else
      LaborOff = rs1.Fields("LABOR_OFF").Value
    End If

hr = DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy", LaborOn), DatePart("m", LaborOn), DatePart("d", LaborOn)) + (DatePart("h", LaborOn) / 24)

Do Until hr > LaborOff
  If LaborOn > hr And LaborOff < hr + 1 / 24 Then
    Hours = (LaborOff - LaborOn) * 24

    ElseIf LaborOn > hr And LaborOff > hr + 1 / 24 Then
      Hours = ((hr + 1 / 24) - LaborOn) * 24

    ElseIf LaborOn < hr And LaborOff > hr + 1 / 24 Then
      Hours = 1

    ElseIf LaborOn < hr And LaborOff < hr + 1 / 24 Then
      Hours = (LaborOff - hr) * 24

    Else
      Hours = 0

  End If

  With rs2
    .AddNew
    !Line_Number = rs1!UNIT
    !SOI = rs1!JOB
    !Employee = rs1!Employee
    !Hour_of_Day = hr
    !Labor_Hours = Hours
    .Update
  End With

  hr = hr + 1 / 24
Loop



rs1.MoveNext

Loop

rs1.Close
rs2.Close

End Function
```

Comment: Show us your data structure, query you tried, expected output? How can we help you from a screenshot?

Comment: OK. How do I upload a sample dataset here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Recursive CTE (Recursive Common Table Expression) to generate collection with hours.

Next you have to join employees data where hour number between hours labor on and labor off

Remain only add CASE WHEN clause to calculate amount of hours

Look at this solution:

```
declare @dataTable table(UNIT int, JOB varchar(5), EMPLOYEE nvarchar(50), LABOR_ON datetime2(0), LABOR_OFF datetime2(0))
INSERT INTO @dataTable
(UNIT, JOB, EMPLOYEE, LABOR_ON, LABOR_OFF)
VALUES
(398,'W9714',N'Ley',DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2015,12,16,11,46,39,0), DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2015,12,16,12,20,07,0)),
(398,'WSP06',N'Cervantes',DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2016,01,22,11,30,28,0), DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2016,1,22,12,25,56,0)),
(398,'DN3RT',N'Miller',DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2015,11,2,13,40,46,0), DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2015,11,2,15,01,12,0)),
(398,'N04TA',N'Kitzmiller',DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2015,10,20,16,22,02,0), DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2015,10,20,19,06,21,0)),
(398,'N2C54',N'Blackwell',DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2015,12,14,5,38,30,0), DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2015,12,14,10,34,46,0)),
(398,'NP02M',N'Perryman',DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2015,10,31,5,20,49,0), DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2015,10,31,12,53,43,0));

WITH hourCTE as (SELECT 0 as [HourNo]
UNION ALL
SELECT [HourNo] + 1 FROM hourCTE WHERE [HourNo] < 23
),
DataWithHours as (
SELECT UNIT
,JOB
,EMPLOYEE
,dateadd(hour,HourNo,cast(cast(LABOR_ON as date) as datetime)) as Hour_of_day
,LABOR_ON
,LABOR_OFF
,hourNo
FROM hourCTE
join @dataTable on [HourNo] between DATEPART(HOUR,LABOR_ON) and DATEPART(HOUR,LABOR_OFF))

SELECT UNIT
,JOB
,EMPLOYEE
,Hour_of_day
,
cast(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,LABOR_ON) = HourNo
THEN
DATEDIFF(SECOND,LABOR_ON,DATEADD(HOUR, 1, Hour_of_day))/cast(3600.0 as decimal)
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,LABOR_OFF) = HourNo
THEN
DATEDIFF(SECOND,Hour_of_day,LABOR_OFF)/cast(3600.0 as decimal)
ELSE
1.000
END as decimal(6,5)) as Labor_Hours
FROM DataWithHours
order by unit,  EMPLOYEE, HourNo
```

Comment: This is really promising Steryd. It doesn't seem to work when someone works through midnight.

Comment: Hey, I figured it out. Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend a table that contains the start and stop time of each shift (work period) per person, so if Bob works 1.75 hours, you would have one row for Bob that started at 6:30am and stopped at 8:15 am.  Your need to show this across three working hours is a presentation issue not a data issue.  You could have a "Hour" table with every hour between 12am and 12pm.  If you joined the Hour table with this new table, you'd get 3 results.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I tried to make the example too simple. You're 100% correct. It's a display/analysis issue. So if I made the table with all the clock hours in it, how would I get the hours worked in that hour?

Is there a way to "dynamically" create that clock hour table on the fly in SQL?